# excel 2010 crashes when printing and print.preview

Tags: excel, vba

**Excel Crashes When use this Macro for print preview and printer window ,so I searched alot on Google to see how to solve this problem ,but i fail.**                                          Here is the code i use to PrintPreview

```
Sub Print_TimeSht()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
  .PrintArea = "$A$1:$Q$599"           ' set print area
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments

        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlPortrait
        .Draft = False
       '.PaperSize = xlPaperA4
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = True
        .Zoom = False
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed

     End With
         Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        With ActiveWindow
         .Zoom = 80
         .SelectedSheets.PrintPreview

        End With
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

so How to solve these Problem i use Excel 2010 32 bit with Win7 32 bit >>??????

Comment: It works fine for me... Try and reinstall the printer drivers.

Comment: i tried to run it on another pc,but the same probel and the pc i tried it on it has no printer connected to it,so what is the probelm ???

Comment: You have to install a printer first. Try installing a pdf printer if you don't have a physical one and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

First, try changing the following line to read 'true'

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

This may produce an error message for use in your google search problem solving.

Other than that, perhaps check the following items:

1) macrosecurity is set to low (to test this, change back to original setting after testing)
2) go to **control panel**, select **uninstall program**, click once on **Microsoft office**  and select **change** then **repair** and let the program check itself for missing .dll files, etc.  The problem could just be a missing .dll
3) if this doesn't resolve the issue, go back to control panel/uninstall/change and this time select **add/remove features**.
    a) ensure all of excel is installed (nothing grayed-out)
    b) ensure, in *office shared features*, that *visual basic for applications* is installed.  Also, in the shared features section, proofing tools are installed.  I keep all excel and all office shared features as installed to ensure all bases are covered.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a little late, but for someone who has the same problem it is good to have a solution.
Sometimes you might not be connected to a printer, to prevent Excel from freezing use:

```
Application.PrintCommunication = False 'above:
    With Activesheet.PageSetup
```

and below

```
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
```